# How to burn .img linux file to DVD?

Tags: windows, linux, iso-image, burning, google-chrome-os

I would like to install Chrome os ( vanilla http://chromeos.hexxeh.net ) on my old Toshiba laptop. I tried to burn the .img file to my USB. But My toshiba doesn't have any USB option in Startup Bios. Therefore, I tried to burn this .img to a DVD. But every time I tried with any burning software on **Windows** I get the message of " **The img file is not supported** ".

So do you have any idea how to burn this image file to a DVD ? Or do you have any other idea to install this Chrome OS on my laptop ?

Thanks

Comment: How old is the laptop? Any recent machine should be able to boot from USB. Try inserting the USB stick and then check the boot order menu in the BIOS.

Answer (score 2):

Simply change the file extension from **IMG** to **ISO**, don't worry nothing will happen to the file, if you're uncomfortable with this you can use [ImgBurn](http://www.imgburn.com/) to burn your file to DVD.

But I do know from Linux that you can't make a bootable CD ISO off a bootable USB, the reason for this is that USB images use syslinux as bootloader (which can only be installed on FAT32) and CD ISO's use isolinux as bootloader (isolinux won't install on anything but iso9660).

In order to get your ChromeOS to boot from a CD, you would actually have to make it a LiveCD, it doesn't come as a LiveCD nor is it offered as a LiveCD. That requires it to be put on a partition on the hard drive and then an image made of that partition so it can be converted to a LiveCD.

Comment: I did it, and burns it too, But is not working .

Comment: You changed the file extension or did you use ImgBurn?

Comment: I did change the file extension, it took me like 5 minutes to burn. When I restart my PC, it doesn't work. I even tried with different computer , but DVD is not working.

Comment: I suggest you revert to the IMG file extension and try to burn it with ImgBurn or [Ultra ISO](http://www.ezbsystems.com/ultraiso/)

Comment: I already used both. The both seems working but somehow, but when I click on disk it says uncorrupted disk. It doesn't make it bootable. After when I select to boot from DVD it skip to HD.

Comment: Since the ChromeOS website recommends [Windows Image Writer](https://launchpad.net/win32-image-writer/) perhaps you should give it a try.

Comment: That's just for USB only.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [unetbootin](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/)? It's the general go-to for writing ISO/etc. to USB.